# Params object[] values is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass 3 strings and a datetime object using params. However, no matter what is sent, values is always null.

```
public ResponseObject Method(params object[] values)
{
    // values is null
    var var1 = Convert.ToString(values[0]);
    var var2 = Convert.ToString(values[1]);
    var var3 = Convert.ToString(values[2]);
    var effectiveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(values[3]);
}
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to create a method that can have optional parameters, but I don't know how many parameters are going to be sent. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I'm new to how this works, but from what I can tell the code is being called through an http request. The request is something along these lines:

```
http://localhost:20559/api/Method?var1=aaa&var2=bbb&var3=ccc&var4=2013-01-30
```

Comment: Show us how you're calling that method and how you're referring to `values` within the method.

Comment: _"However, no matter what is sent, values is always null."_ It would be sufficient to show us one value.

Comment: Please show either the actual calling code or some minimal example showing the undesired behaviour.

Comment: Please show how you call the `ResponseObject Method()` ?

Comment: I showed an example of how it is called, but I'm having difficulty finding exactly where it is called in the code. It is using routing to call the method.

Comment: @BradGermain Well, we can't help you until you find out how it's called, so there's no point in this question existing until you manage to find that.  As it is, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Okay, so this in some way looks like it involves model binding with (some form of) ASP.Net - please add some suitable tags to better distinguish the technologies you're using, e.g. is this method an action in a web api controller? MVC controller? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for continuing to try to help. This is a method in a web api controller. Initially there is a config class that creates routes using the HttpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute method.

Comment: Also, if it helps, it successfully sends data when the method header is something like this: public ResponseObject Method(string var1, string var2, string var3, DateTime? var4 = null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `public ResponseObject Method(object[] values)` to work, the request should look tile this:

```
../api/Method?values=aaa&values=bbb&values=ccc&values=2013-01-30
```

That way you can pass an array with as many items as you like.

However, that is not what I would do.
Just go for:

```
public ResponseObject Method(string var1, string var2, string var3, DateTime? var4 = null)
```

If any parameter is not sent, it'll just be *null*.
Specifying a *nullable* type makes the parameter optional.

Comment: Great, thanks for your input @David! This does seem to solve the issue. I didn't realize you could have more parameters than listed and it will still run properly. This fixes my issue. I still couldn't find why params wasn't working, but this will work. Thanks again!